# How can I set up filters for my woocommerce products?

Tags: woocommerce

I use woocommerce and instead of marking my product page within the woocommerce>config>products section I use a woocommerce shortcode to insert my products into a page. Now whenever I try to use any sort of filter plugin it doesn't work. Is there a way to make filters work with this configuration?

thanks,
Amir

Comment: By default you should have on the page of the shop a drop down with a sort menu , for example : sort by newer, what kind of sort do you want to have ?

Comment: There is no sort option at all for some reason. My guess is that it's because I'm using a woocommerce shortcode (https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) instead of marking the page in the woocommerce configuration as my shop page -> It's not a product archive page. If I mark it in the config area I get the standard dropdown.

Comment: do you have this code: do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' ); on archive-product.php ?

Comment: Hi, yes I have that code on my archive-product.php. I think my woocommerce isn't displaying my products as archive due to using the shortcode. Quite a dilemma because I don't see what the purpose of the shortcode would be if it doesn't allow using filters...

Comment: it's working for me, are you sure you're not missing something? maybe you edit the code and removed something that belongs to it?

Comment: not that I know of. In woocommerce > config > products > display do you have your shop page marked as shop page for this to work? As I've customized the look of the page I dont have the page marked as shop page in woocommerce

Comment: shop is selected on my side

Comment: how did you customize the page if you selected the page as your shop? As you can see my site has several shop pages depending on the product type so I'm not clear how I can achieve this effect for all pages. Do you know of a code I can embed into the html in order to enable the filter system within woocommerce?

Comment: Let me ask it like that, when you want to see your products page you enter to the /shop/ link, right?

Comment: The way the website is set up there are multiple shop pages, such as http://cormilu.com.br/loja/fio-de-luz/ , http://cormilu.com.br/loja/fio-de-luz/ and http://cormilu.com.br/loja/globo/ (can be found under the loja dropdown). The loja page merely contains 6 CTA's. The actual /shop/ page redirects to the loja page because I don't want to use the products archive templates created by woocommerce. On each of the shop pages I've entered woocommerce shortcodes to display the products.

Comment: OK, I see it redirect, so is it a template? or you created the template? if it's a template so it may have been with a lots of changes and it might have been removed, i designed my store so I just created a child-theme by moving the woocommerce/templates/ folder to my theme and that way I managed to design my store from the beginning, and it is there by default, so i just wanted to make sure if you started from scratch or it's a template?

Comment: Hi, I created a new page and added the woocommerce shortcode into the html. I didn't do any modification of templates as I didn't see the need for it. Now I'm considering to change the system in order to get the filters if that's the only way...